# Наша врач или наш врач?

Tags: согласование

Из Валгиной:
Согласование может быть полным: зеленая трава, маленький мальчик, деревянное изделие (согласование в роде, числе и падеже) или неполным: наша врач, бывшая секретарь (согласование в числе и падеже);

С сайта: [Спишу.ру](http://spishy.ru.com/spishi-ru/spishi-ru-russkiy-5-klass-288.html)

Не следует считать словами общего рода существительные мужского рода типа директор, инженер, врач, геолог, которые в равной степени могут быть использованы для названия лица мужского и женского пола, оставаясь при этом существительными мужского рода. Если подобное существительное называет женщину, то определение к нему согласуется по мужскому роду, а сказуемое — по женскому, например: Всю ночь просидела молодой врач у постели пострадавшего (из газет).

Значит, все-таки - наш врач, даже если это женщина?

Answer (score 3):

Такое употребление действительно возможно, но только в непринужденной разговорной речи. В других случаях согласование должно быть в мужском роде.

> В разговорной, непринужденной речи активно распространяются употребления типа врач пришла, бригадир уехала в поле (реже – сочетания типа новая бригадир, прекрасная врач). Такие сочетания представляют собой синтаксическое указание на пол называемого лица – способ, конкурирующий со словообразовательным выражением того же значения. Существительные муж. р. при этом не становятся существительными общего рода. Во-первых, слова типа врач, бригадир последовательно выражают значение мужского рода как в координации со сказуемым, так и в согласовании; ***женский род чаще обозначается координацией и редко – согласованием, причем, как правило, только в им. п. (наша, сама, эта врач, но неправильно – нашу врача, с нашей врачом).*** Во-вторых, при обозначении лица мужского пола эти существительные (в отличие от слов общ. р.) определяются только согласуемыми словами в форме муж. р.: Иванов – хороший врач; Петров – очень грамотный инженер; Он – известный бригадир.
>
> См.: АКАДЕМИЯ НАУК СССР ИНСТИТУТ РУССКОГО ЯЗЫКА РУССКАЯ ГРАММАТИКА

Answer (score 3):

Местоимение "наш" не обозначает специальность, оно оценочное, нейтральное по тематике, поэтому здесь может применяться разговорный стиль.

Иванова - наш врач . Наш врач Иванова (нейтр.) Иванова - наша врач. Наша врач Иванова (разг.)

Сравнить: Известный химик Ярославцева (нейтр.), согласование только в м.роде

Пояснение

**1) Согласование сказуемого**

Корректор исправил ошибки (дел., офиц.). Секретарь записала меня на прием (разг, СМИ, худож.)

**2) Согласование именной части** (при оценке качеств)

Петрова - хороший врач (нейтр.)  Анна Васильевна - опытная врач, очень чуткая, внимательная (разг,. часто при наличии других определений).

Н.М. Малышева была одной из замечательных педагогов по вокалу. Лазутина - одна из прославленных олимпийских чемпионок.

**3) Согласование определения** (при обозначении специальности)

Выдающийся математик Софья Ковалевская, строгий редактор Ирина Сергеевна. Согласование с ближайшим существительным